# Read only the first few lines of text from a file

Tags: c#

How can I read just the first two lines of a file my program saves? (They represent a username and a password.)

Comment: Call ReadLine twice. And find a better mechanism for storing a username and password.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use a [`System.IO.StreamReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx).

```
string line1, line2;

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("myFile.txt")) {
    line1 = reader.ReadLine();
    line2 = reader.ReadLine();
}
```

Or, for something modern:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines("myFile.txt").Take(2).ToArray();
```

Comment: Your code does not handle the case of a file with 0 or 1 line (handling of exceptions).

The second statement would very extremely inneficient for large files since it reads all lines, and allocate and unecessary array

Comment: @karim: a) Exception handling is not, in my opinion, relevant to this answer. b) No, it doesn’t. You might be thinking of `ReadAllLines`; `ReadLines` is an enumerable that reads lines on demand.

Comment: I misread ReadLines, thank you (allocating an array for 2 lines is an overkill in many situations)
As for the exceptions, let the OP decides, at least it has been noted.

Answer (score 2):

For that use `StreamReader.ReadLine()`