# Read only first line from a text file

Tags: c#

so what I'm failing to do is, MyFile.txt has either "english", "french" or "german" in the first line
and I want to get the language from the first line of the text file, then continue my code

```
String[] languages = new String[] { "english", "french", "german"};

foreach (String language in languages)
{
    string line1 = File.ReadLines("MyFile.txt").Skip(0).Take(1);
    line1 = language;
    continue;
}
```

Comment: check this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439733/read-only-the-first-few-lines-of-text-from-a-file

Answer (score 117, accepted):

You can make use of `File.ReadLines` together with `Enumerable.First`.
This guarantees you to only read the first line from the file.

```
using System.Linq;
```

...

```
string line1 = File.ReadLines("MyFile.txt").First(); // gets the first line from file.
```

The difference to `File.ReadAllLines` is, that `File.ReadLines` makes use of lazy evaluation and doesn't read the whole file into an array of lines first.

Linq also makes sure of properly disposing the FileStream.

Comment: @Kiquenet `ReadLines` makes use of lazy evaluation. Meaning it yields line by line. In our case only the first line. `ReadAllLines` however would first read the whole file even though we only need the first.

Comment: I don't know if an empty file returns any line. If not, checking first with `File.ReadLines("MyFile.txt").Any()` will avoid exceptions.

Comment: @marsh-wiggle thats a bad idea, use `FirstOrDefault` instead

Comment: Why? Any() and FirstOrDefault() seem to have excactly the same code. The first returns a bool, the second return an object or null. (Reference: https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs)

Comment: @marsh-wiggle because you can use FirstOrDefault and then check for null if you need the first line or null if the file doesnt exist. Checking with any before would mean that you read the file twice.

Comment: `ReadLines` is available on `.NET 4.0+` only

Answer (score 55):

To comment on the use of `ReadAllLines()` in the OP's comment on the answer of **CSharpie**; it may have a huge impact on the performance if `MyFile.txt` is a very large file.

`File.ReadAllLines().First()` will actually read *all* the lines, store them in a `string[]` and then take the first. Therefore, if your file is very large, it will store all these lines in the array, which might take some time.

An alternative and better performing option would be to just open a `StreamReader` and read only the first line. A correct implementation would be;

```
String[] languages = new String[] { "english", "french", "german"};
string firstLine;

using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("MyFile.txt"))
{
    firstLine = reader.ReadLine() ?? "";
}

if(languages.Contains(firstLine))
{
    //...
}
```

The use of `using` will take care of closing and disposing the reader. Also, using `??` will make sure `null` is never returned (and thus saving you an `ArgumentNullException` on `Contains()`).

Comment: I didnt use File.ReadAllLines but File.ReadLines.

Comment: @CSharpie, my bad, read the comment of the OP and assumed he used `ReadAllLines()`. I edited this in my answer!

Comment: This is a better solution than the accepted solution as it disposes the resources.

Comment: This solution does not read the whole text file just for returning a single line +1.

Comment: @MichaelD this is not true. Using Linq with the File.ReadLines also calls dispose on the FileStream. Thats one of the reasons why IEnumerator is also IDispoasble. Hence Enumerable.First properly disposes it.

Answer (score 3):

If the file is already opened by another process and concurrent reading is allowed, then something like this is needed. Otherwise a share violation exception is thrown.

```
// Usage of "FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite" prevents an avoidable
// exception when file is already opened with concurrent reading by 
// another process
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(@"MyFile.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    using (var readerForFileStream = new StreamReader(fileStream))
    {
        string firstLine = readerForFileStream.ReadLine();

        if (firstLine != null)
        {
            // the file has a line
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Though the post is from 2014, a more efficient solution using a more recent method could be this one:

```
System.IO.StreamReader readingFile = new System.IO.StreamReader(filePath);

string readingLine = readingFile.ReadLine();
```

This way you prevent reading several lines and needing to get the first one with Linq.

Comment: Was this method existant in 2014? [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx), the documentation dates form 2016.

Comment: I didn't notice the date of the original question until after I posted the answer, however, I didn't take it down because it could still be of benefit for someone else, edited the answer to make this clarification

Comment: This is the same as Dion V's answer.

Comment: @CSharpie but worse since he's not using a `using` or `readingFile.Dispose()`