# Reading respective lines of multiple text files to be combined

Tags: c#

Firstly, I'm new to C# and I'm having a hard time figuring out how I'd go about doing this.

Basically, I have multiple text files all with their own types of data. My aim is to read the first line of each of these files and combine them into one string so that I can sort them later by their respective days.

For example, in the first line of each file there could be the values...

- File 1: 16/02/15
- File 2: Monday
- File 3: 75.730
- File 4: 0.470
- File 5: 75.260
- File 6: 68182943

So I'd like to combine them in a string like so "16/02/15 Monday 75.730 0.470 75.260 68182943"

I'd also want to do this for the second, third, fourth line etc. There are a total of 144 entries or lines.

Here is the code I have so far. I'm unsure if I'm on the right track.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace BankAlgorithms
{
    class Algorithms
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Saves each individual text file into their own string arrays.
            string[] Day = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\computing\Desktop\algorithms\CMP1124M_Assigment_Files\Day.txt");
            string[] Date = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\computing\Desktop\algorithms\CMP1124M_Assigment_Files\Date.txt");
            string[] Close = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\computing\Desktop\algorithms\CMP1124M_Assigment_Files\SH1_Close.txt");
            string[] Diff = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\computing\Desktop\algorithms\CMP1124M_Assigment_Files\SH1_Diff.txt");
            string[] Open = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\computing\Desktop\algorithms\CMP1124M_Assigment_Files\SH1_Open.txt");
            string[] Volume = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\computing\Desktop\algorithms\CMP1124M_Assigment_Files\SH1_Volume.txt");

            //Lists all files currently stored within the directory
            string[] bankFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\computing\Desktop\algorithms\CMP1124M_Assigment_Files");

            Console.WriteLine("Bank Files currently saved within directory:\n");
            foreach (string name in bankFiles)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(name);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\nSelect the day you wish to view the data of (Monday-Friday). To view a grouped \nlist of all days, enter \"Day\"\n");
            string selectedArray = Console.ReadLine();

            if (selectedArray == "Day")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Opening Day File...");
                Console.WriteLine("\nDays grouped up in alphabetical order\n");

                var sort = from s in Day
                           orderby s
                           select s;
                foreach (string c in sort)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(c);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: All files have the same number of lines in them?

Comment: What results are you getting? Have you tried stepping through the code with the debugger and examining the variable values?

Comment: A little bit off-topic, but where do the files come from? do you have any control over how they are made in the first place? a file containing just a list of dates etc isn't very useful and might be worth just writing a useful file in the first place

Comment: @Shar1er80 all files have the same amount of lines in them, correct.

Comment: @CraigW. Currently I just have the dates arranged and grouped up in an alphabetical order.

Comment: @Sayse The files are already created and no modification is allowed.

Comment: Well, then following up on Shar1er80's comment, just loop through with a for loop and then construct a list based on the items from each array at each index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this might be a little more than you strictly need, but I think it'll be robust, quite flexible and be able to handle huge files if need be.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      //  const string folder = @"C:\Users\computing\Desktop\algorithms\CMP1124M_Assigment_Files";
        const string folder = @"C:\Temp\SO";
        var filenames = new[] { @"Date.txt", @"Day.txt", @"SH1_Close.txt", @"SH1_Diff.txt", @"SH1_Open.txt", @"SH1_Volume.txt" };

        var dataCombiner = new DataCombiner(folder, filenames);
        var stockParser = new StockParser();
        foreach (var stock in dataCombiner.GetCombinedData(stockParser.Parse)) //can also use where clause here
        { 
            if (ShowRow(stock))
            {
                var outputText = stock.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(outputText);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static bool ShowRow(Stock stock)
    {
        //use input from user etc...
        return     (stock.DayOfWeek == "Tuesday" || stock.DayOfWeek == "Monday")
                && stock.Volume > 1000 
                && stock.Diff < 10; // etc
    }
}

internal class DataCombiner
{
    private readonly string _folder;
    private readonly string[] _filenames;

    public DataCombiner(string folder, string[] filenames)
    {
        _folder = folder;
        _filenames = filenames;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> GetFilePaths(string folder, params string[] filenames)
    {
        return filenames.Select(filename => Path.Combine(folder, filename));
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetCombinedData<T>(Func<string[], T> parserMethod) where T : class
    {
        var filePaths = GetFilePaths(_folder, _filenames).ToArray();
        var files = filePaths.Select(filePath => new StreamReader(filePath)).ToList();

        var lineCounterFile = new StreamReader(filePaths.First());
        while (lineCounterFile.ReadLine() != null)// This can be replaced with a simple for loop if the files will always have a fixed number of rows
        {
            var rawData = files.Select(file => file.ReadLine()).ToArray();
            yield return parserMethod(rawData);
        }
    }
}

internal class Stock
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string DayOfWeek { get; set; }
    public double Open { get; set; }
    public double Close { get; set; }
    public double Diff { get; set; }
    public int Volume { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        //Whatever format you want
        return string.Format("{0:d} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5}", Date, DayOfWeek, Close, Diff, Open, Volume);
    }
}

internal class StockParser
{
    public Stock Parse(string[] rawData)
    {
        //TODO: Error handling required here
        var stock = new Stock();
        stock.Date = DateTime.Parse(rawData[0]);
        stock.DayOfWeek = rawData[1];
        stock.Close = double.Parse(rawData[2]);
        stock.Diff = double.Parse(rawData[3]);
        stock.Open = double.Parse(rawData[4]);
        stock.Volume = int.Parse(rawData[5]); 
        return stock;
    }

    public string ParseToRawText(string[] rawData)
    {
        return string.Join(" ", rawData);
    }
}
}
```

PS:
Instead of reading it from the file, I'd rather also calculate the DayOfWeek from the Date. 
Also be careful when parsing dates from a different locale (eg. USA vs UK). 
If you have an option I'd only use the ISO 8601 datetime format.

Comment: PS:  Instead of reading it from the file, I'd rather also calculate the DayOfWeek from the Date. Also be careful when parsing dates from a different locale (eg. USA vs UK). If you have an option I'd only use the ISO 8601 datetime format.

Answer (score 0):

Access your file strings from a collection, use this code to read from each file and use a StringBuilder to build your string.

[Read only the first few lines of text from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439733/read-only-the-first-few-lines-of-text-from-a-file)

```
var builder = new StringBuilder();
foreach(var file in fileList)
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file))
    {
        builder.Append(reader.ReadLine());
    }
}

return builder.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use following approach: put all in an `string[][]` first, then it's easier:

```
string[][] all = { Day, Date, Close, Diff, Open, Volume };
```

To get the minimum length of all:

```
int commonRange = all.Min(arr => arr.Length);
```

Now this is all you need:

```
string[] merged = Enumerable.Range(0, commonRange)
    .Select(i => string.Join(" ", all.Select(arr => arr[i])))
    .ToArray();
```

This is similar to a `for`-loop from 0 to `commonRange` where you access all arrays with the same index and use `String.Join` to get a single `string` from all files' lines.

---

Since you have commented that you want to merge only the lines of a specific day:

```
var lineIndexes = Day.Take(commonRange)
    .Select((line, index) => new { line, index })
    .Where(x => x.line.TrimStart().StartsWith("Monday", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    .Select(x => x.index);

string[] merged = lineIndexes
    .Select(i => string.Join(" ", all.Select(arr => arr[i])))
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: So going on from that, how would I progress to enable the user to select the data ranges to display using the days as a search input. So if they input Monday it would display all data entries for every monday.

Comment: @jmg2015: so the user inputs `Monday` and you want to look into the `Day`-file to see on which line(s) it is? Then pick the same line(s) from the other files?

Comment: Yes, so it would display all Mondays and the respective data from the same lines in other text files.

Comment: @jmg2015: have a look at my revised answer. `"Monday"` is a string literal, but of course you can also use a variable that was specified from  the user.

Comment: Thanks Tim, and to display the results within the cmd, I'd just be using a Console.WriteLine?

Comment: @jmg2015: use whatever you want. You could even use a multiline TextBox. `textBox1.Lines = merged`;