# How to Import Flat File in SSIS with different first Row Header Columns and Appending Headers to each data row

Tags: sql, visual-studio, ssis, flat-file

I'm trying to load data from a fixed width flat file in SSIS (2008 R2), but the first row contains data that:

1. Needs to be parsed with different fixed widths than the data below it and
2. The parsed data from that first row needs to be appended to each
   item in the data below it, after that data has been separately parsed.

What is the best way to approach this? I'm relatively new to SSIS, so I've tried using a Row Count and a conditional split to separate out the first row, but I'm not sure how to parse the data outside of the Flat file importer.  I've read that using a Script Transform could work, but I don't know what the code should be...

By way of example, if I had flat data that looks like:

> Hamilton Beach      20150410    Sunny 
>   Bob   Male  Blue Black 
>   Bill Male  BrownBrown 
>   GeorgeMale  GreenBlonde 
>   JackieFemaleGreenBlack 
>   Jill FemaleBlue Black

It should be in the output table as:

> Hamilton Beach,    20150410,   Sunny,  Bob,    Male,   Blue,   Black
>   Hamilton Beach,    20150410,   Sunny,  Bill,   Male,   Brown,  Brown
>   Hamilton Beach,    20150410,   Sunny,  George, Male,   Green,  Blonde
>   Hamilton Beach,    20150410,   Sunny,  Jackie, Female, Green,  Black
>   Hamilton Beach,    20150410,   Sunny,  Jill,   Female, Blue,   Black

Answer (score 0):

You are in luck. SSIS does not support mixed record types but you can get away with it because you only have 1 header row.

My implementation would look like a Script Task that reads the first line of my file and a Data Flow task that reads the rest of the data.

[image]

### Read the first line

This one is simple. Create an SSIS Variable, call it `FirstLine` of type String. Pass that value as a read/write value into a script task.

[image]

Use the code from this answer

[Read only the first few lines of text from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439733/read-only-the-first-few-lines-of-text-from-a-file)

Now you simply need to push the value of `line1` into our SSIS level Variable. That looks like

```
Dts.Variables["User::FirstLine"].Value = line1;
```

This assumes you want the whole line stored into FirstLine. If you need to portion it out into individual fields, then you'll need to implement that logic. You don't provide guidance on how to delimit "Hamilton Beach 20150410 Sunny" into individual pieces but the above logic holds true. Parse and assign into different SSIS level variables.

My specific implementation created 3 SSIS Variables, all of type string

- User::HeaderIHaveNoIdeaWhatThisIs
- User::HeaderObservationDate
- User::HeaderWeather

The following code represents what's already been linked

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ST_7edd5e6df63a4837afac15b86c21d639.csproj
{
    [System.AddIn.AddIn("ScriptMain", Version = "1.0", Publisher = "", Description = "")]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {

        #region VSTA generated code
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion


        public void Main()
        {
            // User::HeaderIHaveNoIdeaWhatThisIs,User::HeaderObservationDate,User::HeaderWeather

            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439733/read-only-the-first-few-lines-of-text-from-a-file
            string line1 = string.Empty;

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\ssisdata\so_29811494.txt"))
            {
                line1 = reader.ReadLine();
            }

            // Magic here to understand how to split this out. Assuming this is also fixed width
            // Horrible, hard coded brittle approach taken
            //Hamilton Beach      20150410    Sunny
            string h1, h2, h3;
            h1 = line1.Substring(0, 20).TrimEnd();
            h2 = line1.Substring(20, 12).TrimEnd();
            h3 = line1.Substring(32, line1.Length - 32);

            Dts.Variables["User::HeaderIHaveNoIdeaWhatThisIs"].Value = h1;
            Dts.Variables["User::HeaderObservationDate"].Value = h2;
            Dts.Variables["User::HeaderWeather"].Value = h3;

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

### Read the rest of the data

In your flat file connection manager, you want to change the value for Skip header rows from 0 to 1. This indicates that validation of data and parsing should not begin until we've read the first N rows. Define your connection manager as usual.

[image]

[image]

Connect a Data Flow Task to the above Script Task. Within the Data Flow Task, use a Flat File Source and connect a Derived Column Component. The Derived Column Component is how we're going to get the value from our SSIS Variable into the data flow. Add a new column called `HeaderColumn` and use an expression like `@[User::FirstLine]`.

[image]

[image]

If you notice that the column on the right indicates a data type of `DT_NTEXT`, that's probably not going to match the target column definition. You might need to do something like substring the variable `SUBSTRING(@[User::FirstLine], 1, 20)`. That results in a data type of DT_WSTR and a length of 20. You goal is to make this match the target definition.

You may also need to make that a DT_STR data type instead of DT_WSTR. In that case, add an explicit cast into your substring operations `(DT_STR, 20, 1252)SUBSTRING(@[User::FirstLine], 1, 20)`

### Source data

I defined my file based on supplied data (click edit on question to get definitions without the stripping of white space)

```
Hamilton Beach      20150410    Sunny
Bob   Male  Blue Black
Bill  Male  BrownBrown
GeorgeMale  GreenBlonde
JackieFemaleGreenBlack 
Jill  FemaleBlue Black
```

Comment: This is helpful, but I'm not sure how to arrange the elements in control flow or DFT to make this work.  Do I need two flat file connection streams?  Also, I am looking to parse the first line into 3 different components.  So, would I have to pass these into variables and then add those as columns? if so, how is this done?)...  I'm feeling I  kind of need an ELI5 here...

Comment: @user3236992 Not sure what ELI5 but I didn't use one here. It's all native SSIS. Parse the first line into a string. Then split that based on whatever rules you need. You'll observe that I made the assumption that the header was fixed width as well but used a different sizing than the data proper. Only you are going to know whether that's the correct approach to take.